# In which type of situations we can use "I Were"?

Tags: grammar, rules

In some situations, we can use "were" with "I" although its grammatically wrong. But somehow it's being used many times, I don't know the situations any idea guys??

Comment: Your question is general reference. You can say "I were" after **if**, **I wish** and **if only**.

Comment: "O, that I were a glove upon that hand, That I might touch that cheek!" - Romeo & Juliet, Act 2.

Comment: “Unless I were already dead....”, “Suppose I were to tell you...”  Neither of those is “grammatically wrong”.

Comment: For example, "If I *were* seven feet tall, I'd be a great basketball player" is grammatical. See here for more explanations: http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/verbs.htm#subjunctive

Comment: It's not "grammatically wrong".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*I were*, used in the kind of contexts Irene has mentioned in her comment, has traditionally been regarded as a subjunctive from. It is certainly grammatical. The authors of ‘The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language’, however, refer to it as '**irrealis**, indicating that it conveys varying degrees of remoteness from factuality.' Their view is that the difference between *were* and *was* in such constructions ‘is one of style level . . . *were* [being] somewhat more formal than *was*.

Comment: The authors of CGEL undoubtedly had great intentions when they tried to change the name to *irrealis*, but I expect that on the whole, they created more confusion than they cleared up.

Answer (score 1):

It’s not grammatically wrong.

We use “If I were,” “if he were” etc. for:

1. If/Unless Clauses

   ex. If I were you, Unless I were you
2. Conditional Clauses (omitted “If”)

   ex. Were I you
3. Wishes

   ex. I wish I were rich.
4. Doubts or Supposition

   ex. Suppose that I were to join.
5. Together with “As if/though”

   ex. He looks as if/though he were drunk.
6. Some fixed expressions

   ex. as it were, would that it were

You can use this structure particularly when writing about something hypothetical, unlikely, or contrary to fact.

Comment: Sorry about the numbers. I can't seem to make them work

Comment: Fixed it for you.